# MAMP not detecting git cloned folders

Tags: mamp

Inside `htdocs` if I create a folder, I can see it using `mkdir test`. However, if I use `git clone {address}` MAMP does not detect it. The permissions are the same (I even tried `chmod 777` the files) but it still does not show up.

Unlike it not existing (NOT FOUND), it shows up as FORBIDDEN.

Answer (score 1):

Okay this seemed to be because I had a link called `index.html` inside, which was linking to a non-existent file.

This folder contained a `create-react-app`.